# std::map - reordering mapped values after item erase

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

Good Day,

I am using std::map to tie row entry of a table to the key item

example :

```
std::map<int,int> myMap;

myMap[13]=0;
myMap[15]=1;
myMap[1]=2;
myMap[5]=3;
...
...
```

Add/update item operation

```
std::map<int,int>::iterator it;
it=result_RecordList.find(methodID);
if(it==result_RecordList.end())
{
    //new item , new row record
}
else
{
    //get record row id and update that item    
}
```

The key is actually objectID of its display on the table

Once I delete the row 2; I want myMap[5] to map to row 2 now.

I cant use row id as key as I often reference the table using objectID

It will be easier for me to reassign the values mapped to the keys if the map elements maintains their order as they were inserted, even the Unordered Map doesn't this

Any solutions welcomed,
Thank you...

---

Currently I have thought of this. Welcome any efficient solution

```
//after myMap erase item
std::map<int,int>::iterator itReassign;

for(itReassign=myMap.begin();itReassign!=myMap.end();itReassign++)
{//for loop
    if(itReassign->second>rowID)//all value above the rowID will be downshifted
    itReassign->second=itReassign->second-1;
}//for loop
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to your problem might be to simply use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) containing the object identifiers. Insert the object ids in the vector in the order you want them displayed, and then loop over the vector from the beginning to the end to display the items. If you then remove an object id from the vector, you automatically "shift" the object ids below it up one step.

However, this solution will change the O(1) access of `std::map` to find the row for a certain object id to O(n).

---

Another possible solution is to use the scheme you have now, but don't look at the value in in the `std::map` as the row, but simply as a sorting order. But then you might be better off with a [Boost bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) instead, so you can go both ways.

Comment: +1 - I don't see any alternative to either a O(n) search or "reindex" on row deletion, even with bimap....

Comment: @Joachim I cant use `std::vector`, the `stl::map` allows me to reinsert the same objectID again so that i can update new info to the same row. I have updated the question to show this

Comment: @JamesG First a note of terminology, if you use the array-index syntax on the map, you don't "reinsert", you *update* the entry in the map. And yes it can be done in a vector as well, just more verbose. And the update/insert code you show in your updated question is just as easy to do with a vector (you might want to read about e.g. [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) here).

Answer (score 0):

With your new solution you can try upper_bound method
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/upper_bound/
and then iterate until end

```
myMap.std::map<char,int>::iterator itup = = myMap.upper_bound (rowId);
while(itup!=myMap.end();++itup)
{
    (*itup)--;
}
```